# phpmyadmin shows Error in processing request popup

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

When I open the table in phpmyadmin and try to do anything with database it shows the below error in popup, how can i resolve this?

```
Error in processing request
Error text: error (rejected)
It seems that the connection to server has been lost. Please check your network connectivity and server status.
```

Comment: Please check your network connectivity and server status.

Answer (score 9):

Change the address in your browser from "localhost" to "127.0.0.1".

Comment: What's the point of this answer? You don't even know if he's running phpmyadmin locally.

Comment: not using either

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem in chrome.

Reboot PC not helped, increase post_max_size not helped.

So, i open phpmyadmin in mozilla, and error was gone.

Problem was in AdBlock extension and table name include text "ads".

I allowed http://localhost/phpmyadmin in AdBlock and error was gone, hope, this will be helpful.

Answer (score 6):

This problem could be due to default limit of importing SQL file into the MYSQL.
you need to increase default size limit.
For that open **php.ini** file and change `post_max_size` value and save the file.
and restart the xampp and try re upload the same file.

Comment: This must be the best answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I had this error, I had script blocking enabled for the page, with Noscript.

When I allowed the javascripts on the page, the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I have this Warning just when i come back to my laptop after putting it to 'sleep'. It seems to be an 'network connectivity' advise.

Comment: I think it has to do with ajax and CORS. Observed the problem with plesk phpmyadmin integrations.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my PHP MYADMIN.there are two ways to do this. first, you can change your URL "localhost"> "127.0.0.1" or  I changed memory_limit to -1 in php.ini file. And now the problem is fixed :).

Comment: That is essentially the same as the top voted answer from two years ago. Could you share what the second way is to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Cookies...

For my part, it was a very long list of cookies that cause the problems.

My phpmyadmin was a docker running on the same port as a lot of other docker, one at a time. The cookie list was growing, being too big for the browser/server/...

The problem was visible since in private windows, or using another browser show no problem.

Cleaning my cookies was (part of) the solution.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was Trend Micro blocking it with this rule:

```
1000608 - Generic SQL Injection Prevention
```

I could see that phpmyadmin was sending xhr requests in the background to `/lint.php` which were getting blocked.  Once I set the rule to detect only and pushed the policy, it started working.

Answer (score 0):

I just getting this error, the problem is in the database. I copy my database with another name and all is fixed.

Comment: after a day I tried to open the table in my old database and no problem, it's back as normal.

Answer (score 0):

This error occured because your xampp control panel MySQL is not on or enable. Soenable it then this error automatically solve.

Answer (score -1):

neither of the above worked for me
so I still have the problem
but a faster a faster solution I used
is to use The SQL CREATE TABLE Statemet
CREATE TABLE table_name (
column1 datatype,
column2 datatype,
column3 datatype,
....
);

Answer (score -1):

## Update:

## After SSL installation the issue solved automatically.

I still getting this bad error and couldn't find and fix it.

Server type: MySQL
Server version: 8.0.27-0ubuntu0.21.04.1 - (Ubuntu)
Protocol version: 10
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8mb4)

Apache/2.4.46 (Ubuntu)
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 7.4.16
PHP extension: mysqliDocumentation
PHP version: 7.4.16

phpMyAdmin
Version information: 4.9.10